# Avoiding database when checking for existing values

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures

Is there a way through hashes or bitwise operators or another algorithm to avoid using database when simply checking for previously appeared string or value?
Assuming, there is no way to store whole history of the strings appeared before, only little information can be stored.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What is the number of previously appeared strings you are looking at?

Comment: What is the number of previously appeared strings you are looking at?
-- 30-40 a day and growing. They are in fact file names built using GUIDs and time stamps, so they are fairly unique to each other, but the task is to filter out the exact file names that already appeared before and let through the new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in Bloom filters. They don't let you authoritatively say, "yes, this value is in the set of interest", but they do let you say "yes, this value is *probably* in the set" vs. "no, this value definitely is *not* in the set". For many situations, that's enough to be useful.

The way it works is:

- You create an array of Boolean values (i.e. of bits). The larger you can afford to make this array, the better.
- You create a bunch of different hash functions that each take an input string and map it to one element of the array. You want these hash functions to be independent, so that even if one hash function maps two strings to the same element, a different hash function will most likely map them to different elements.
- To record that a string is in the set, you apply each of your hash functions to it in turn — giving you a set of elements in the array — and you set all of the mapped-to elements to TRUE.
- To check if a string is (probably) is in the set, you do the same thing, except that now you just check the mapped-to elements to see if they are TRUE. If all of them are TRUE, then the string is probably in the set; otherwise, it definitely isn't.

If you're interested in this approach, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter for detailed analysis that can help you tune the filter appropriately (choosing the right array-size and number of hash functions) to get useful probabilities.